# Datagrid markChanged X++ (AX Dynamics 2012)

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

In a form there's datasource, the **datasource** content is a **table**. this table is the datasource of a grid. then I have `markChange` override method on the table to do business logic when I'm selecting record/s on the grid.

Now the question is, if my **form** **datasource** is a **Query** how could I do the **markChange** event?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a query to your datasources node of your form it should expand with all the tables in the query.

On the first table you can just override the `markChanged` method and it will be triggered when you select a record using the checkbox.

The `markChanged` is triggered on the first table though, not on the others.